# CMake builds seems to be not parallel in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

CMake builds seems to be not parallel in Android Studio. How to make build process parallel (Building multiple source files the same time)? I know that for non-android builds with Unix Makefile generator you should pass `-jN` argument to `make`. I wasn't able to find much information about this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking CMake is not parallel, but CMake doesn't build, it generates files for make/ninja/etc.

Studio invokes CMake with `-G Ninja` (it's actually some special Android Studio flavor for IDE support, but it's Ninja at the core), which generates ninja files, and *ninja* is parallel. You don't need to pass `-j` with ninja, it's automatic.

What makes you say it isn't parallel?